# Python - get redirected URL from Google's "I feel lucky" and Duckduckgo's "I'm feeling ducky"

Tags: python, http, python-2.7, redirect

I need to write a Python function that all it does is to take a link from Google's "I feel lucky" or Duckduckgo's "I'm feeling ducky" and return its redirection. for example, the function shuld take :

```
http://www.google.com/search?q="stackoverflow"&btnI
```

or

```
https://duckduckgo.com/?q=!stackoverflow
```

and return:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/
```

I searched and didn't found a thing.
Thanks.

Comment: What have you searched for? Where have you searched?

Comment: stackoverflow & google for url redirection with python

Comment: Have you taken a look at my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can use the [requests](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests) package:

```
import requests

var = requests.get(r'http://www.google.com/search?q="stackoverflow"&btnI')
print var.url
```

Comment: +1 Probably should add `allow_redirects='false'` to prevent actually fetching the target page.

Comment: @Robᵩ I really hate passing booleans into functions.