# Javascript: Get redirected link from Google's "I'm feeling lucky" function

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I need to write a Javascript function that takes the redirected link from Google's "I feeling lucky" button.

The function should take:

```
http://www.google.com/search?q="stackoverflow"&btnI
```

and return:

```
https://stackoverflow.com
```

I've tried:

```
function getRedirect(url) {
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'followRedirects': true, 'muteHttpExceptions': true});
  var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location']; // undefined if no redirect, so...
  var responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
  if (redirectUrl) {                                   // ...if redirected...
    var nextRedirectUrl = getRedirect(redirectUrl);    // ...it calls itself recursively...
    Logger.log(url + " is redirecting to " + redirectUrl + ". (" + responseCode + ")");
    return nextRedirectUrl;
  }
  else {                                               // ...until it's not
    Logger.log(url + " is canonical. (" + responseCode + ")");
    return url;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work since it only handles http redirects. I suppose Google's I'm feeling lucky button works differently.

Comment: My apologies, I was assuming the same format from this question would work (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728252/python-get-redirected-url-from-googles-i-feel-lucky-and-duckduckgos-im-f) I've updated the question with what I've attempted.

Comment: I couldn't find a solution for this so I just used PHP to get final redirect via cURL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to retrieve an URL of `https://stackoverflow.com` of the redirect link from `http://www.google.com/search?q="stackoverflow"&btnI`.

If my understanding is correct, how about this modification?

#### Modification points:

- In this case, please use `followRedirects: false`.
- You can retrieve the URL from both header and response body.

#### Modified script:

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=%22stackoverflow%22&btnI';
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {'followRedirects': false, 'muteHttpExceptions': true});
var redirectUrl = response.getHeaders()['Location'];
Logger.log(redirectUrl) // https://stackoverflow.com
```

Also you can retrieve the URL as follows.

```
var redirectUrl = response.getContentText().match(/HREF=\"(\w.+)\"/)[1];
Logger.log(redirectUrl) // https://stackoverflow.com
```

#### Note:

- If you use `http://www.google.com/search?q="stackoverflow"&btnI`, please do URL encode like `http://www.google.com/search?q=%22stackoverflow%22&btnI`.

  - You can also use `http://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow&btnI`.

#### Reference:

- [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.